# How can I set a constant number as the lowest number in a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Here is my query?

```
UPDATE users 
SET reputation = reputation - (CASE WHEN id = 29 THEN 2 
                                    WHEN id = 30 AND NOT 0 THEN 15
                                    ELSE 0 
                               END)
WHERE id IN (30, 29);
```

Sometimes it throws this error:

> #1690 - BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(spy.users.reputation - (case when (spy.users.id = 29) then 2 when ((spy.users.id = 30) and (not(0))) then 15 else 0 end))'

As you see in the error message, `reputation` column is *UNSIGNED*, and I need to keep it `1` at least .. something exactly like stackoverflow: if a user has 1 rep and he gets a downvote, his rep will still remain `1`. Well how can I fix that update query to prevent failing in such a case?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here: `WHEN id = 30 AND NOT 0`?

Comment: @sgeddes `WHEN id = 29` is OP and `WHEN id = 30` is responder.  Also `AND NOT 0` checks the responder isn't the OP.

Comment: I guess I'm just not sure how `not 0` is helping here.  Which field is it referring to?  Assuming the `id`, if it's 30, how could it be 0?  Maybe I just don't understand it's usage...

Comment: @sgeddes that `0` isn't always `0` .. it can also be `1` .. I manage it by PHP and then pass it to the query.

Comment: So as in a boolean instead?  `not 0` being true with`not 1` being false?  I think I get it now, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: If id is 30 then it's safe to assume it's not 0. The two positions are mutually exclusive,

Comment: @Strawberry I don't get your mean ..

Comment: OK. How can zero be one?

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not sure what you want to understand .. but like this: `GREATEST( ..., 1)`

Comment: No, you've lost me I'm afraid, but it seems someone here's on your wavelength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `greatest()`:

```
UPDATE users       
    SET reputation = GREATEST(reputation -
                              (CASE WHEN id = 29 THEN 2 
                                    WHEN id = 30 AND NOT 0 THEN 15                                       
                                    ELSE 0 
                               END),
                              1)  
    WHERE id IN (30, 29);
```

EDIT:

Try this version:

```
UPDATE users           
SET reputation = (CASE WHEN reputation > (CASE WHEN id = 29 THEN 2 
                                               WHEN id = 30 THEN 15 
                                               ELSE 0 
                                          END)
                       THEN reputation - (CASE WHEN id = 29 THEN 2 
                                               WHEN id = 30 THEN 15 
                                               ELSE 0 
                                          END)                                 
                       ELSE 1                            
                   END)      
WHERE id IN (30, 29);
```

The problem is the intermediate calculation.  I thought MySQL might do the intermediate calculation correctly, and then fail on the assignment.

Comment: Well thank you .. upvote ... just why `, 0)` ? I mentioned I want `1` as lowest value ..

Comment: Also [that error is still there](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfp6o.png) ... I mean using `greatest()` doesn't make any different.

Comment: Your second version works as well .. Also for your information, I can simply use `CAST()` function in this case instead of those nested `case .. when`. Here is [the final query](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/120bfdfde349ace4c0323f9570179a67) which works perfectly.

Comment: @M.Dogru . . . You can read Chapter 1 of the Second Edition of "Data Analysis Analysis Using SQL and Excel".  The indentation style that I use is explained there.  Please refrain from editing my code in the future.